# No option to add CallKit privacy permission with Xcode 8

Tags: ios, callkit

We are using Xcode 8 to build our VoIP app and are using the CallKit framework. In the Xcode Info plist settings there is no option to set CallKit privacy, also when we download the app onto a iOS device running 10.2, iOS does not request the users permission to use call kit. Has this been dropped from iOS now?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CallKit has not needed permission since iOS 10 beta 3

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, you just need enable Background modes, with those Capabilities

- Audio, AirPlay, and Picture in Picture
- Voice over IP
- Background fetch

and add Mircophone usage description in your Info.plist file.